# How to iterate over rows and print out CSV::Table values in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, loops, csv, object, sinatra

I'm making a simple Sinatra app and have the following 'numbers.csv' file:

```
Name,Title,Phone
Ally Smith,Manager,888-552-444
Rick Jones,Director,888-552-447
Hayley Bowman,Accountant,888-552-424
```

The task is to print the name and phone numbers in an erb file.

I originally solved this problem with nested arrays:

```
get '/' do
  # turns CSV into array with nested arrays
  @names = CSV.read('names.csv')
  # delete headers
  @names.shift
  erb :index
end
```

and an each loop:

```
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>

  <% @names.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%= row[0] %> </td>
    <td> <%= row[2] %> </td>
  <tr>
  <% end %>
```

Now I am trying to overcome my fear of working with objects and hashes, so I am approaching the problem like this:

```
get '/' do
  # turns CSV into object with key value pairs
  @numbers = CSV.read('numbers.csv', headers:true)
  erb :index
end
```

I know that the benefit of using a CSV::Table object with headers means that I can access the values like so:

```
@names[i]["Name"]
@names[i]["Phone"]
```

where `i` is the counter for each row, followed by the key names.

I tried writing a while loop in the erb file – fail. Also a foreach loop that I understand is as CSV method and modified my code accordingly – fail.

I'm having trouble iterating over the rows and calling the specific keys.

I'm not sure if I am using the right loops.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have been working on this for hours :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine. As i show below:

```
> numbers = CSV.read('numbers.csv', headers:true)
> numbers.each do |row|
>     puts "#{row['Name']} - #{row['Phone']}"
>   end

Ally Smith - 888-552-444
Rick Jones - 888-552-447
Hayley Bowman - 888-552-424
```

I think your problem is your variables. you should use `@numbers` instead of `@names` in your second example:

```
@names[i]["Name"] # should be @numbers[i]['Name']
```

Comment: Thanks you @JCorcuera. Much appreciated :)